# C++ Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'theArray' was corrupted

Tags: c++, runtime-error

this is actually my first time posting on this website. I am having a problem using ctsrings. The purpose of this function is to define my own version of the strcat function.
My code:

```
void mystrcat(char destination[], const char source[])
{

    int i = 0;
    while (destination[i] != '\0')
    {
        ++i;
    }

    int w = 0;
    while (source[w] != '\0')
    {
        ++w;
    }

    int numOfElements = i;
    int q = 0;
    while (q < w)
    {
        destination[numOfElements] = source[q];
        ++q;
        ++numOfElements;
    }

    i += q;


    for (int c = 0; c < i; ++c)
    {
        cout << destination[c];
    }


}
```

For some reason, whenever I run my program with two prices of random cstrings (for example, "cdvfvf" and "gfgfgd"), the program does output the correct combined answer, but right after that it gives me the "corrupt stack" around the array error. Again, if my description of either the purpose of my code or the problem just doesn't make sense, really sorry. And thank you to whoever responds.

Comment: "corrupt stack" means you wrote to one index too far past end of your array 97% of the time, and 3% you wrote to index -1.  Ergo  "`destination[numOfElements] = source[q];`" is your error.

Comment: Show the part of your program where you call the function.

Comment: The part of the code containing the variable "theArray" would be relevant.

Comment: @user3512751 - If the answer that Vlad from Moscow gives is correct, then believe it or not, there is nothing wrong with your code. The code is working as designed, since strcat() works the same way. You give strcat() a short destination buffer, and the program may crash in the same way.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie strcat adds the final `'\0'` but his code doesn't.

Comment: @agbinfo - Yes, but my main point is that the assignment `The purpose of this function is to define my own version of the strcat function`, implies that the mystrcat() function *should* behave badly if it is given bad arguments, no different than strcat().

Comment: Hi guys, this is how I call my function from my main:

Comment: char theArray[] = "abc";
    const char appendedArray[] = "def";

Comment: mystrcat(theArray, appendedArray);

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and my point is that his function was behaving badly even when given good arguments.

Comment: @user3512751 You're calling your function incorrectly. `theArray` should contain enough space to accommodate both strings. Try `char theArray[40] = "abc";` and use Vlad's fix.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the array `destination` is not large enough to store the concatenated string.

For example for these string literals `"cdvfvf"` and `"gfgfgd"` the size of the destination array must  be equal to at least 13.

Also take into account that after this loop:

```
while (q < w)
{
    destination[numOfElements] = source[q];
    ++q;
    ++numOfElements;
}
```

there should be

```
destination[numOfElements] = '\0';
```